# data Is not inserted to sql database using dataadapter..?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

Here is the code

```
string constr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Inventory.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Users", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommandBuilder cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
            sda.Fill(ds, "Users");
            DataRow row = ds.Tables["Users"].NewRow();
            row[0] = 2;
            row[1] = txtUsername.Text;
            row[2] = txtPassword.Text;
            ds.Tables["Users"].Rows.Add(row);
            int res=sda.Update(ds, "Users");
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            dgUser.ItemsSource = null;
            dgUser.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["Users"].DefaultView;
            ds.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
```

Problem is it is executing without error but when you check in the database there will be no insertion of record... what might be the error..?

Comment: Did you check that ds is getting user's table records??

Comment: I tried to execute your code with my tables and it works fine.

Comment: Actually It is not inserted but It can display the data from table.

Answer (score 1):

try doing an insert instead of a select

```
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into Users (ID, UserName, Password) VALUES (2," + 
       txtUsername.Text + ", " + txtPassword.Text + ")", con);
```

but inline SQL is a bad idea generally. It would be better to write a stored procedure and execute that from your code

Comment: I tried that too.. cmd.ExecuteNonQuerry() returns one row is affected but data is not inserted into table

Comment: can you insert when you use the same syntax in the sql server management studio? With the same login credentials

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't see any mistake in the code. Can you try debugging with breakpoints and see if the row is correctly added to the dataset before passed on to the DB?

Comment: Yeah.. I tried that too.. Dataset is added with row perfectly. sda.update returns one row is affected .. But data is not added to the table

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the [`InsertCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand.aspx) for the DataAdapter ? without setting it its unlikely the adapter would know to insert your record.

you need something like

```
cmd ="INSERT INTO ...."; // add param to this

sda.InsertCommand = cmd
```

Try updating after setting this.(Similarly do it for `UpdateCommand` for the Adapter if required)

Comment: He is using the Update method of SqlDataAdapter. He does not need to configure Insert or Update Command.

Comment: @nevayeshirazi i think that is applicable only if `SelectCommand` is used else you have to....

Comment: You are right I just saw it on MSND but his code worked just fine on my pc.